# Qt Designer on OSX continually asks to reload resources file

Tags: c++, macos, qt, pyqt4, qt-designer

I am using PyQt with Qt version 4.8.5 on a networked OSX 10.9.2 platform. As long as I have designer opened it constantly (about one a minute) informs me that the resources file has been modified outside designer, and would I like to reload it?

Everything works, but it is MADDENING to have this dialog come up so often when the file hasn't been modified at ALL!

Has anyone else seen this behavior? My suspicion is that it has something to do with working in a networked (server mounted home directory) environment...

Comment: It's a bug, probably nobody bothers to test Qt Creator in an environment like that. Just report it as a bug.

Comment: Another suggestion: Qt Creator is open source. It'll take you maybe 30 minutes to rebuild it, and maybe another few minutes on top of it to get rid of the notification code as a temporary workaround.

Comment: I agree that nobody thought to test Qt Designer in a shared environment, I will go back and try to report the bug again. Their reporting system isn't the easiest to use... :-) Thanks for the work around idea, that would also allow me to run it under Python 3.x too! Since the Homebrew install bug hasn't been fixed yet either!